# divergence theorem applied to a tensor dotted with a vector

Tags: integration, tensor-products, tensors

Is my expression for the divergence theorem correct?

$\int_{V}\underline{v}.div(\underline{\underline{\tau}})dV=\int_{S}\underline{v}.\left(\underline{\underline{\tau}}.\underline{n}\right)dS$

and would this be equal to

$\int_{S}\left(\underline{v}.\underline{\underline{\tau}}\right).\underline{n}dS$

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vec v$ is a vector and $\vec \tau$ is a tensor (dyadic), then using the product rule differentiation for the Divergence along with the Divergence Theorem yields

$$\begin{align}
\int_V \vec v \cdot (\nabla \cdot \vec \tau) \,dV&=\int_V \left(\nabla \cdot (\vec \tau\,\cdot \vec v)-(\vec \tau^T \cdot \nabla) \cdot \vec v\right) \,dV\\\\
&=\oint_S \hat n\cdot \vec \tau \cdot \vec v\,dS-\int_V (\vec \tau^T \cdot \nabla)\cdot \vec v\,dV
\end{align}$$

where $\vec \tau^T$ is the transpose of the tensor (dyadic) $\tau$.

Comment: hi, tau is a tensor. does that make a difference?

Comment: Nice answer. I have almost fallen into the error of transposed tensor. (some author would like to use double dot notation, even easier to be confused). I try to understand the formulae like this and please correct me if something went wrong. $\nabla\cdot(\vec\tau\cdot\vec v)=\hat e_i\cdot\partial_i(\vec\tau\cdot \vec v)=\hat e_i\cdot(\partial_i\vec\tau)\cdot v+(\hat e_i\cdot\vec\tau)\cdot\partial_i \vec v=(\hat e_i\cdot\partial_i\vec\tau)\cdot \vec v+\vec\tau^T\cdot(\hat e_i\partial_i)\cdot \vec v$. The last term may be also $\vec\tau^T:\nabla\vec v$.